# Set up a counter after app is launched in swift 3?

Tags: swift3

How do I detect when the app is first launched and then add plus one to an integer every 24 hrs since the app was first launched?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track on how many days have passed since your app was launched for the first time, there is a better approach.

Store the current date for a key (it's called `firstLaunchDate` here) if there is no value for that given key.

Put this code inside your `AppDelegate` class:

```
struct UserDefaultsKeys {
    static let firstLaunchDate = "firstLaunchDate"
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.firstLaunchDate) == nil {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.firstLaunchDate)
    }

    return true
}
```

If you want to retreive the number of days since the first launch, you should calculate it with `Calendar`'s `dateComponents` method:

```
if let firstLaunchDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.firstLaunchDate) as? Date {
    let startOfCurrentDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let startOfFirstLaunchDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: firstLaunchDate)

    if let daysSinceFirstLaunch = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startOfFirstLaunchDay, to: startOfCurrentDay).day {
        print("days since the first launch:", daysSinceFirstLaunch)
    }
}
```